# Which plugin will be the best for generating report in TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using Testng framework for WebDriver. I have to generate custom reports. I tried ReportNG but I am facing some problem in ReportNG. So I am looking for some other alternative of ReportNG. Can you please suggest me some other plugin which will be compatible with TestNG.

Comment: u can use extent report .... its a good reoprting tool

Comment: I like using Allure as my reporting tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also suggest [allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/) but you can also look into [AUT Reporter](http://automationtestingutilities.blogspot.in/p/reporting.html) for the same.

Comment: Currently I am not using any build Automation tool. Can I Integrate Allure without any build tool like Maven?

Comment: No, If you are using TestNG then suggested way is to use Maven and add required dependencies.

Comment: Thank You dwivedi for the reply. I will check the feasibility and I will try to move my project on Maven.

Answer (score 3):

Yo can try this one - [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/). It provides some useful annotations and nice report.

Comment: Currently I am not using any build Automation tool. Can I Integrate Allure without any build tool like Maven?

Comment: @Sharfi, you can do it without build tools, but with maven or gradle it would be easier. How are you going to run test on a CI-server without it?